# Saving JavaScript sessionstorage.getitem('var'); in database

Tags: javascript, php, sql, mariadb

I want to insert JS variable value into database

```
echo $date = "<script>document.write(sessionStorage.getItem('ss_date_month'))</script>"."<br>";
```

this is how I'm getting the variable and trying to save in database, it echo the value of `$date`

```
     $sql44 = "INSERT INTO `pickup`
           ( `address`, `add_line_2`, `driver_message`, `time`, `price`, `s_m_l`)
           VALUES ( '$s_pickup_address', '$s_florr_building_fp', '$s_driver_message_fp', '$date', '$price', 'NULL')";

           $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql44);
           if ($run_query) {
               echo "query chal gyi";
          }        
    else{
        die("Connection Failed". mysqli_error($con));
    }
```

Output:
`10 April // value of $date.`

Error:

> Connection FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ss_date_month'))
>   ', 'pricee', 'NULL')' at line 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: `'NULL'`, as a string literal?

Comment: don't worry about the null just a placeholder for now

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo $date = "<scri...
```

to

```
echo "date = $date", "<scri...
```

What you have is changing `$date`.